# How do I evaluate the integral $\int \frac{1}{x\sin x}dx$?

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

$$\int \frac{1}{x\sin x}dx$$

Is this integral computable? I tried with Wolfram Alpha; it says

[Standard computation time exceeded](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int+1%2F%28x+sin+x%29).

Comment: $x=1/y \implies \int \frac{y}{\sin \frac{1}{y}}dy$ but still seems problematic

Comment: You forgot to multiply by $\frac{-1}{y^2}$ in your substitution. Making that substitution would actually yield $\int \frac{-1}{y \sin (1/y)} dy$. (But this doesn't really help!)

Answer (score 5):

As another answer pointed out, this can't be computed in terms of elementary functions.  In general, you can use the Risch algorithm to determine if a function has an anti-derivative expressible in terms of elementary functions (see e.g. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Risch_algorithm ) and the Risch algorithm correctly identifies this example as not being integrable in terms of elementary functions.